# Running tomcat on 80 or 8080 port

Tags: windows, tomcat

People, help! For two days to dig, I do not understand why ...
There are domain name love-chatruletka.ru, it looks at 176.58.60.212 settings registrar 2domains.ru.
When prescribe 8181 port settings tomkat server, such reference works: love-chatruletka.ru:8181, but when I write ports 8080 or 80, you do not!
Tell me why ?! Who knows?
Scour the forums, people have such a problem too .. But while I do not understand the decision. I have a virtual server - windows 8

I have these settings:

```
<Connector port = "8181" protocol = "HTTP / 1.1"
               connectionTimeout = "20000"
               redirectPort = "8443" />
.......
 
<Host name = "love-chatruletka.ru" appBase = "webapps" unpackWARs = "true" autoDeploy = "true">
<Alias> love-chatruletka.ru </ Alias>
<Context path = "" docBase = "rouletteChat" debug = "0" privileged = "true" />
<Valve className = "org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory = "logs"
prefix = "localhost_access_log." suffix = ". txt"
pattern = "% h% l% u% t & quot;% r & quot;% s% b" resolveHosts = "false" />
</ Host>
```

In the Control Panel \ System and Security \ Administrative Tools Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager I do not have ...
Ie I do not have IIS, which could block like that.
Tomkat server runs quietly, which is port 80, which is the port 8080. This means that the port is not busy ....
That's what could be wrong? Who can tell? Thanks

Comment: What You understand under words "nor work"? Example of error?

Comment: Page not available by adress http://love-chatruletka.ru:8080 and http://love-chatruletka.ru. But http://love-chatruletka.ru:8181 available/ Ports in tomcat config changed